# Make "Offtopic -- problem that can't be reproduced" as separate close reason

Tags: feature-request

When reviewing the "vote to close" queue I see a number of "off topic" votes.  When I look at the question, it seems perfectly on-topic.  But when I dig deeper, it's because of a typo or a simple mistake.  And so the question was closed off-topic "Questions describing a problem that can't be reproduced and seemingly went away on its own (or went away when a typo was fixed) are off-topic as they are unlikely to help future readers."

Now I'm not arguing that this isn't a valid reason to close a question.  Clearly it is.

What I'm asking is whether this should be made a *separate* reason; not 'off topic' but its own reason for closing.  This will make it easier for reviewers to understand the close reason.  Because as it stands, seems a little too broad in the review queue.

Comment: It was [status-declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196383/307535) a few years ago, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

I agree. It's also occurred to me that placing non reproducible issues under the off topic hierarchy does not really make sense, because if a problem is not reproducible, that does not make it off topic.

Is this issue specific to U&L? If not, it should be moved to the main Meta Stack Exchange site.